# What software do I need to create a website which automatically sends price comparisons of specific groups of products to consumers?

Tags: comparison

I have an idea but I have no technological background. Here is the idea:

1. The following information is collected from the customers:
   •   Products they are looking for (e.g. trainers, jeans, t-shirts, hoodies, bags).
   •   Sizes for each product category.
   •   Budget for each product category.
   •   Favourite brands for each product category.
   •   Colours for each product category.
2. Website searches all leading online luxury retailers and automatically sends the best deals and sale items based on the customer’s saved preferences. A list of suitable deals are sent to the customer via email on a weekly basis, or alternatively, the customer can log in to their account via our website in order to view their up-to-date deals selection.
3. Customers can change their preferences at any time via the website and the following week’s selection will be updated accordingly.

(Website needs to be able to send deals of multiple brands for different product categories e.g. customer wants hoodies from Nike, Adidas or Puma and wants trainers from New Balance or Converse)

What software will do this/where can I get this software?

Thanks!
Olly.

Comment: Your question is ridiculously broad, and also subjective. It also asks for recommendations, which are off-topic for StackOverflow. *However*, as a bare minimum, you will need: A database to store your users and their preferences, a server-side scripting language to connect to said database, a script to scrape products from other websites (in accordance with both the law and the respective site policies) on a regular interval (like a cronjob), and another script to send emails. You'll also need both a registration system and a login system.

Comment: You won't go wrong with Amazon.